# Cloud Foundry registration email not received

Tags: email, authentication, registration, cloud-foundry

I signed up for a Cloud Foundry account, received a welcome email:

*Thank you for your interest in Cloud Foundry - the industry's first open platform as a service.
You are now registered with CloudFoundry.com. You will receive an email shortly at xxx@gmail.com with your credentials and instructions on how to get started.
Happy Clouding,
The Cloud Foundry team*

BUT never received the aforementioned second mail with my credentials. Tried with a different email, but no luck. Any suggestions?

Comment: Would you mind posting this same question to [the Cloud Foundry mailing list](https://groups.google.com/a/cloudfoundry.org/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/vcap-dev)?  Thanks!